# Not beautiful json array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the json array:

```
{    
"ServerInfo" : {
"vkapikey" : "e28003ds382nsd9805fe0b6fbg1jkh3b12lk1ab23491205e3f17484f30ef40031c0464",
"vksecretkey" : "dlfJFshasdsDMNN",
"vkreturn" : "152f81",
"version" : "5.80",
"groupid" : "159344234"
  }
}
```

When I have `json _decode()` and then again `json_encode()` after that it becomes so:

```
{"vkapikey":"e28003ds382nsd9805fe0b6fbg1jkh3b12lk1ab23491205e3f17484f30ef40031c0464","vksecretkey":"dlfJFshasdsDMNN","vkreturn":"15asd2fs3f81","version":"5.80","groupid":"159344234"}
```

How to make it so that he does not become so not beautiful?

Comment: Thats actually a JSON representation of an Object not an array

Comment: Why? JSON is not really for human consumption... it lacks bacon.

Comment: Every array are beautiful !

Comment: If you encode an array/object as JSON, then it removes the unnecessary spaces.

Comment: PHP offers *pretty*, but not *beautiful*. Hopefully that's enough.

Comment: You can use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as an argument of `json_encode`

Comment: **That does not happen** when I do what you say you are doing !!! SO what else are you doing

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```